# MikroORM - Non-FK'd ID conditional join

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

I have inherited this strange database schema, where there's a jsonb field, and on that json is a userId, and userType. There are also two user tables, representing different user types. The table that `userId` joins to is dependent on `userType`.

Now I'm sure I can use query builder to piece together the appropriate SQL, but I currently have a very dynamic system that translates GQL to Mikro filters, so any manual piecing together complicates things.

Is there any possible way I can do something like

```
@Entity()
class Job {
  @Property({ type: 'jsonb' })
  props: unknown

  @Formula(alias => `select user.name, user.dob, user.etc from user where user.id = ${alias.props->>userId`)
  user: User
}
```

or something similiar? Basically using decorators to define how to retrieve those pieces of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual relation, you just need to use the relation decorator with the `formula` option instead of the `@Formula` decorator directly.

Something like this should work:

```
@ManyToOne({
  entity: () => User,
  formula: alias => `${alias}.props->>userId`,
})
user: User
```

Here is a working example doing something similar in the ORM tests:

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/tests/issues/GH4759.test.ts#L34

Here is how you could handle the different types:

```
@ManyToOne({
  entity: () => User,
  formula: alias => `case when ${alias}.userType = 'manager' then null else ${alias}.props->>userId end`,
  hidden: true,
  nullable: true,
})
user?: User;

@ManyToOne({
  entity: () => ManagerUser,
  formula: alias => `case when ${alias}.userType = 'manager' then ${alias}.props->>userId else null end`,
  hidden: true,
  nullable: true,
})
manager?: ManagerUser;

@Property({
  persist: false,
})
get userOrManager(): User | ManagerUser | undefined {
  return this.userType === 'manager' ? this.manager : this.user; 
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, that should get me most of the way there. The only part missing is the return type of the Entity is dependent on another field, `userType`. `entity: (e) => e.userType === 'manager' ? ManagerUser : User` is there any way to achieve this sort of behaviour? Or at least tell Mikro which table to join on.

Comment: I would just define two properties, one for each type, that's the least hackish way.

Comment: And you could then define a virtual property that will give you one or the other (as a getter), keeping those two explicit properties as hidden.

Comment: updated the answer with example of this approach

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, that's a great approach. Will give this a go. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: What about accepting the answer?

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Accepted.